# iOS UITableViewCell Optimization

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, smooth-scrolling

In my app I have a UITableView that contains custom UITableViewCells. Scrolling is very sluggish and laggy, and I need to resolve this.

Each cell contains 5-6 labels, a few buttons, and an image.

I have a xib for the cell, where I place the buttons, labels, and image view, but I set all of the images in cellForRowAtIndexPath. To load the images I use [UIImage imageNamed:@""], which I read is better for optimization. I am also the reusing cells.

I also found that even if I comment out and do not set the images, the table still is laggy, with just the labels set with text.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to have a rather complex table cell while still having good, smooth performance? Is having the custom cell as a xib hinder performance?

Comment: It would be helpful to see your `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Make sure you really are reusing cells.  Make sure that the cell
   identifier you are using is set in the XIB of the `UITableViewCell`
   in interface builder.
2. Use less transparency in your subviews.  If at all possible, go into your labels and make sure their background matches with that of the background of the cell.
3. Check for unoptimized code.  For example, if you're displaying a formatted date and are creating an instance of `NSDateFormatter` each time `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called, this will really bog down your app.
4. Use Instruments with the Timing and Core Animation modules to find where the bulk of your time is spent.  Ultimately, these can reveal where the true performance problem lies.

Comment: I actually realized I never set the cell identified in the xib, so once I did that scrolling without the images is very smooth now. I also set my labels to solid colors and not transparent. Like I said now without loading the 1 UIImageView the cells scroll smoothly, but when I put the image back it scrolling lags a bit but not nearly as much as before. Thanks!

Comment: I am also calculating a date in my cellForRowAtIndexPath:, I am going to move that out as well and get those dates before I load the table.

Comment: Do you know if `NumberFormatter` has the same performance impact as `NSDateFormatter`?

Comment: @CSjunkie I would expect performance issues to be the same, but you could also profile this Instruments to get a definitive answer. I’d probably do it on the oldest supported device to get a worst case scenario picture.

Answer (score 4):

Implement a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and do your own drawing in `drawRect:` on one opaque `UIView`.

Doing it that way speeds up scrolling a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In IB set some properties to NO.

In scrollers, set "Horizontal scrolling" to NO.
In Touch, set "Delay content touches" and "Cancellable content touches" to NO

It will enable smooth scrolling you'r table view

Comment: Thanks I set all of those to NO and it did seem to help a bit, thanks!